# What is an algorithm to compute the minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

For characteristic polynomial, there is a very straight forward algorithm.

> Compute  $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$

Now I have looked for the method for calculating minimal polynomial everywhere but could not find an algorithm even for a 2x2 case.

Give a simple matrix, say

$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$

How can we calculate its minimal polynomial?

Comment: you can try to solve linear equations, check whether or not
\begin{align*}
A&\in kI\\
A^2&\in kA+kI\\
A^3&\in kA^2+kA+kI\\
&\text{etc.}
\end{align*}

Comment: yoyo how does this help I am desperate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2 x 2 case, here's an algorithm: Compute the characteristic polynomial. If it's not a perfect square, then it actually IS the minimal polynomial. If it IS a perfect square, say $(x - a)^2$, then your matrix is either $aI$, in which case the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)$, or it's not, in which case the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)^2$.

Why does this work? 1. The minimal polynomial always divides the characteristic polynomial.

2. The minimal polynomial of the Jordan form is the same as the minimal polynommial of $M$. If $M$ has two distinct eigenvalues, then its jordan form is 
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \lambda_1 & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda_2
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   and it's evident that the minimal polynomial of this is $(x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)$.

If it has duplicate eigenvalues, then the Jordan form looks like either
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 1 \\
0 & \lambda_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In the first case, your matrix is conjugate to $\lambda_1 I$, hence must equal $\lambda_1 I$, whose minimal polynomial is $(x - \lambda_1)$.

In the second case, the matrix doesn't satisfy that polynomial, so the min poly must have two $(x - \lambda_1)$ factors, hence must be $(x - \lambda_1)^2$.

Comment: Can you illustrate with an example for my pea brain for the second case?

Comment: Any reference helps

Comment: I hope my additional comments clarify things.